# Kendo Diagram Connection Schema

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik, diagram

I am trying to create a diagram with Telerik kendo diagram. Since I get every shape and its connection from my database the attributes of my data source object to not match the required naming. To fix this problem I used "schema" for the shapes as you can see in my screenshot:

[image]

Since it is working for the shapes, I tried to use the same strategy for the connections, but it is not working. I did some research and found the following which does not use schema at all.

[image]

Is there any way to use schema for the connection?

Answer (score 0):

The [API](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/diagram/configuration/connectionsdatasource) indicates the 'from' and 'to' fields in the connectionsDataSource refer to the 'id' of the dataSource. Have you tried to set a [schema.parse](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/schema#schemaparse) function? It will be executed before the response is used and can be used to map the response - [example](https://dojo.telerik.com/EqeCeZIW).

```
  var connDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport:{
        read:{
          url:"https://run.mocky.io/v3/8930bf8f-3bf0-422c-ba93-36a0662338f0"
      }
    },
    schema: {
      parse: function(response) {
        var data = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
          var itm = {
            from: response[i].source,
            to: response[i].destination,
            label: response[i].label
          };
          data.push(itm);
        }
        return data;
      }
    }
  });
```